# Spring Data JPA: relationship table based on property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a software that has two entities that can have relationships. They are called `Authority` and `Notice`. A notice can link to an authority and an authority can link to another authority. The image below shows an example of this relation.

[image]

The columns `origin_type` and `origin_seq_no` columns has the information of the relationship. The first row says that the `notice` `id` `20` has a relation with the `authority` `423`. The second line is an authority linking to another authority.

I managed to successfully map this table with two classes.

The key class:

```
public class AuthorityLinkId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7116265461694208810L;

    private AuthorityLinkOriginType originType;
    private int originSeqNo;
    private int originField;
    private String originSubfield;
    private Authority authority;
    private int authorityField;
    private String authoritySubfield;

    public AuthorityLinkId() {
    }

    public AuthorityLinkId(AuthorityLinkOriginType originType, int originSeqNo, int originField, String originSubfield, Authority authority, int authorityField, String authoritySubfield) {
        this.originType = originType;
        this.originSeqNo = originSeqNo;
        this.originField = originField;
        this.originSubfield = originSubfield;
        this.authority = authority;
        this.authorityField = authorityField;
        this.authoritySubfield = authoritySubfield;
    }
}
```

And the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authority_link")
@IdClass(AuthorityLinkId.class)
public class AuthorityLink implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2198430222226373395L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "origin_type")
    private AuthorityLinkOriginType originType;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "origin_seq_no")
    private int originSeqNo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "origin_field")
    private int originField;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "origin_subfield", columnDefinition = "char", length = 1)
    private String originSubfield;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="authority_id",nullable = false)
    private Authority authority;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "authority_field")
    private int authorityField;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "authority_subfield", columnDefinition = "char", length = 1)
    private String authoritySubfield;

}
```

My question is: how do I create the properties in the `Notice` and `Authority` class to retrieve the set of `AuthorityLink`. Remember that when the relation is in the `Notice` class the `origin_type` has to be `bibliographic`, when Authority `origin_type` has to be `authority`.

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = AuthorityLink.class, mappedBy = "what_do_I_put_here")
private Set<AuthorityLink> authorityLinks;
```

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `mappedBy` attribute is the name of the persistent attribute on the other side, through which this link should be established. In case of `Authority` this would be `authority`. Since you don't have a field `@ManyToOne Notice notice` in `AuthorityLink` there is no possible `mappedBy` value you can set. Probably you need to use the `origin_seq_no` as join column for `Notice` so that you can do this.